# How to map every element and its children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dictionary

I am trying to get every element and alls its children and there children and add them to a list. But at the moment its only showing the first two children.

Is there a better way for doing this?

here is jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/7mNsH/2/

here is what i have so far

```
$('#main').children().each(function(){
    var classs = $(this).attr('class');
    $('#hell ul').append('<li class="'+classs+'">'+classs+'</li>');
});

<div id="main">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="innerinner"></div>

    </div>
    <div class="inner2">
        <div class="inner2inner2">
            <div class="inner2inner2inner2"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

so at the moment its currently showing this

```
<ul>
<li class="inner">inner</li>
<li class="inner2">inner2</li>
</ul>
```

but i need it to look like this

```
<ul>
   <li class="inner">inner
      <ul>
         <li class="innerinner">innerinner</li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li class="inner2">inner2
    <ul>
         <li class="innerinner">innerinner
         <ul>
            <li class="inner2inner2inner2">inner2inner2inner2</li>
         </ul>
         </li>
    </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be looking for a *[recursive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science))* solution.  If you look at your current code, what you are accomplishing is iterating over #main's children, appending them to a ul, and then finishing.  You need to be sure to keep checking each child for their own children (and all of their children!) in order to get the fully recursive list of children.

Check out  working JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/uK6kG/5/

```
function listChildren(element, container) {
    //Get the current node's class
    var parentClass = element.attr('class');
    //Go ahead and construct a list element
    var parentContainer = $('<li class="' + parentClass + '">' + parentClass + '</li>');
    //Now iterate over the current node's children (if there are any)
    if (element.children().length > 0) {
        var childList = $('<ul></ul>');
        element.children().each(function () {
            //Recursively call the list children function!
            listChildren($(this), childList);
        });
        //Actually add the children to the current node
        parentContainer.append(childList);
    }
    //Add us to our own container
    container.append(parentContainer);

}
$('#main').children().each(function () {
    listChildren($(this), $('#list-container #top-ul'));
});
```